# iPhone - How to deal with multiple UIImagePickerControllerDelegate?

Tags: iphone, delegates, uiimagepickercontroller

I am developing an simple application scanning QR code. To scan QR code I am using one delegate method as shown below.

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
```

Also I have another delegate method for source type camera to take a picture.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo
```

I have 2 buttons for scanning QR and to take picture. But the problem is when I take a new photo also the

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
```

method is called. How to solve this. When I select photo button I need to call the specific delegate method and when I call select the QR button I need to call the other delegate method.

Comment: You can use simply `flags` to differentiate the button clicks

Comment: @Maulik can you please brief about it.

Answer (score 0):

First - it's worth mentioning that this method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img 
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo
```

is deprecated since iOS 3.0. The only method to use now is

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker  
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

(you get the image reference out of the dictionary)

To answer the question: you need a way of identifying each `picker` in the delegate callback. One way to do this would be to make a couple of properties, one for each picker, and set the property when you invoke the picker...

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIImagePickerController* QRpicker;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIImagePickerController* cameraPicker;
```

creating your QRPicker...

```
 UIImagePickerController* QRpicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
         //configure QRPicker
 [self presentViewController:QRpicker];
 self.QRpicker = QRpicker;
```

do the same for the cameraPicker

Then you just need to check which type of picker invoked the delegate method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker  
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
  if ([picker isEqual:self.QRPicker])
      //code for QRPicker delegate
  else 
      //code for cameraPicker delegate
```